# WPF datagrid sorting fails for enum with converter

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, enums, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with the following column, which binds to an `enum` named `Type` with a converter.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" 
 Binding="{Binding Path=Type,Converter={StaticResource EnumStringConverter}}" />
```

It displays the converted values properly. But it fails at sorting.

[image: Ascending sort goes wrong]

[image: descending sort goes wrong too!]

The correct order for ascending sort should have been `Cash, Debt Security and Gold` or reverse for descending sort.

The Enum is defined as

```
enum SomeType
{   
    Cash = 0,
    Gold = 1,

    // few more values ...

    DebtSecurity = 6,
}
```

I have also tried to use the `SortMemberPath="Type"` for the column but still gives the same result. Am I missing something very basic here?

Comment: Your grid is still sorting the enum and not the string. Maybe instead of converter, create another property in your viewmodel, which converts the enum to string and use that instead

Comment: Yes, I was looking for an explanation as to why is that happening? and more of a XAML oriented solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive searching and find some answers in parts, I could merge the available answers to solve a generic requirement of this sort.

So, if you want to enable sorting by your enum's converted values.

1) Add the following conveerted-enum-sorting class

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows a grid to be sorted based upon the converted value.
/// </summary>
public static class GridEnumSortingBehavior
{
    #region Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseBindingToSortProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseBindingToSort", typeof(bool), typeof(GridEnumSortingBehavior),
                                           new PropertyMetadata(UseBindingToSortPropertyChanged));

    #endregion

    public static void SetUseBindingToSort(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(UseBindingToSortProperty, value);
    }

    #region Private events

    private static void UseBindingToSortPropertyChanged(DependencyObject element, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = element as DataGrid;
        if (grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var canEnumSort = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (canEnumSort)
        {
            grid.Sorting += GridSorting;
        }
        else
        {
            grid.Sorting -= GridSorting;
        }
    }

    private static void GridSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var boundColumn = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
        if (boundColumn == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Fetch the converter,binding prop path name, if any
        IValueConverter converter = null;
        string bindingPropertyPath = null;
        if (boundColumn.Binding == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var binding = boundColumn.Binding as Binding;
        if (binding == null || binding.Converter == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        converter = binding.Converter;
        bindingPropertyPath = binding.Path.Path;
        if (converter == null || bindingPropertyPath == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Fetch the collection
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        var lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
        if (lcv == null || lcv.ItemProperties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Fetch the property bound to the current column (being sorted)
        var bindingProperty = lcv.ItemProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == bindingPropertyPath);
        if (bindingProperty == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Apply custom sort only for enums types
        var bindingPropertyType = bindingProperty.PropertyType;
        if (!bindingPropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Apply a custom sort by using a custom comparer for enums
        e.Handled = true;
        ListSortDirection directionToSort = boundColumn.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending
                                                 ? ListSortDirection.Ascending
                                                 : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        boundColumn.SortDirection = directionToSort;
        lcv.CustomSort = new ConvertedEnumComparer(converter, directionToSort, bindingPropertyType, bindingPropertyPath);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

2) Add a custom comparer that compares the enum values based on their converted values

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the value of enums and then compares them
/// </summary>
public class ConvertedEnumComparer : IComparer
{

    #region Fields

    private readonly Type _enumType;
    private readonly string _enumPropertyPath;
    private readonly IValueConverter _enumConverter;
    private readonly ListSortDirection _directionToSort;

    #endregion

    public ConvertedEnumComparer(IValueConverter enumConverter, ListSortDirection directionToSort, Type enumType, string enumPropertyPath)
    {
        _enumType = enumType;
        _enumPropertyPath = enumPropertyPath;
        _enumConverter = enumConverter;
        _directionToSort = directionToSort;
    }

    #region IComparer implementation

    public int Compare(object parentX, object parentY)
    {
        if (!_enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // extract enum names from the parent objects
        var enumX = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(parentX)[_enumPropertyPath].GetValue(parentX);
        var enumY = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(parentY)[_enumPropertyPath].GetValue(parentY);

        // convert enums
        object convertedX = _enumConverter.Convert(enumX, typeof(string), null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        object convertedY = _enumConverter.Convert(enumY, typeof(string), null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

        // compare the converted enums
        return _directionToSort == ListSortDirection.Ascending
                               ? Comparer.Default.Compare(convertedX, convertedY)
                               : Comparer.Default.Compare(convertedX, convertedY) * -1;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

3) Finally to use this on any `DataGrid` simply mark the behavior as `True`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataCollectionWithEnumProperty}" 
yourbehaviors:GridEnumSortingBehavior.UseBindingToSort="True" >
```